# Как исправить ошибку invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'parts_edit' in request.POST:
    PartPost = int(request.POST['parts_edit'])
    PartID = Part.objects.get(id=PartPost)
    if PartID:
        PartID.save()
        added = 'Запчасть успешно отредактированна'
    else:
        error = 'Ошибка редактирования'
```

Передаю данные из формы и при передачи в int выдает ошибку.(передаю строку из букв и цифр)

Comment: Сделай print в PartPost. Что выведет?

Comment: int может только цифры воспринимать, строка из букв и цифр не воспримется, вы хотите только цифры из строки взять? покажите, как выглядит эта строка

Comment: @CrazyElf вот тут есть более полный код(вопрос другой но код тот же) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1409345/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83

Comment: Да что толку от кода, вы скажите, что у вас в `request.POST['parts_edit']`?

Comment: В `request.POST['parts_edit']` пустая строка (это даже в тексте ошибки видно, `''` в конце - это именно она). Пустую строку в целое число нельзя преобразовать. Как исправить - добавить в if проверку на пустую строку, например.

Comment: @insolor Да, упустил я эту деталь